# Remove inaccessible Mongo shard

Tags: mongodb, sharding

I have a MongoDB sharded setup with 3 shards: shard0000, shard0001 and shard0002. The machine that runs shard0002 is down now, which causes all my queries to fail. I'd like to temporarily remove shard0002 from my setup and keep working with the first two shards. That should be doable assuming I only use unsharded collections that reside in the first two shards, right?

What I tried first is: `db.runCommand({removeshard: 'IP:PORT'})` which obviously doesn't help, because it just puts the shard in draining mode, which will never end (since it's down). Then I tried connected to my config server and did `db.shards.remove({_id: 'shard0002'})` on the config DB then restart mongos so it reloads the config. Now whenever I try to do anything I get "can't find shard for: shard0002".

Is there any way to just let Mongo know that I don't care about that shard for now, then re-enable it later when it becomes available.

Comment: You say all queries fail? Does this include queries that can work with just a single shard that is still alive?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Manually modify the the shard entry in the config db, then `removeshard`

Comment: UNHELPFUL.  Need detail or link to how to do this.  What collection?  where?  how to modify it?   ????

Comment: @KevinJ.Rice, in the config db, there is a collection called shards. You will want to remove the shard entry from there manually.

Answer (score 12):

I had a different problem, and I manually removed the shard with:

```
use config
db.shards.remove({"_id":"shard0002"});
```

Comment: Does not work (in version 4.2). If the client tries to access any chunk from removed shard, then you still get an error.

Answer (score 1):

I tried several options to do this in version 4.2.

At the end I ended to these commands to be executed on Config Server:

```
use config

db.databases.updateMany( {primary: "shard0002"}, {$set: {primary: "shard0000"} })
db.shards.deleteOne({_id : "shard0002" })
db.chunks.updateMany( {shard : "shard0002"}, {$set: {shard: "shard0000"} })

while ( db.chunks.updateMany( {"history.shard" : "shard0002"}, 
      {$set: {"history.$.shard": "shard0000"} }).modifiedCount > 0 ) { print("Updated") }
```

It works to a certain extent, i.e. CRUD operations are working. However, when you run `getShardDistribution()` then you get an error **Collection 'db.collection' is not sharded.**

Finally I see only one **reliable & secure** solution:

- Shut down all mongod and mongos in your sharded cluster
- Start available shards as standalone  service (see [Perform Maintenance on Replica Set Members](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/perform-maintence-on-replica-set-members/index.html))
- Take a backup from available shards with `mongodump`.
- Drop data folders from all hosts.
- Build your application newly from scratch. Startup all mongod and mongos
- Load data into new cluster with `mongorestore`

Perhaps for large cluster you have to shuffle around a bit like this:

- Deploy Config servers and mongos server, with one empty shard
- 1. Start one old shard as standalone
  2. Take backup from this old Shard
  3. Tear down this old shard
  4. build a fresh empty new shard
  5. add new shard to your new cluster
  6. restore data into the new cluster
  7. backup can be dropped and shard can be reused in new cluster
- Repeat above for each shard you have in your cluster (the broken shard might be skipped most likely)